# On Dihedral group, action of cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Consider $D_{n}$, Dihedral group of order $2n$.

It has the following presentation, $$D_{n}=\;\langle a,b\;|a^{n},\;b^{2},\; b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\rangle$$

Now consider the cyclic group generated by $b$ and denote it by $C_{2}$, consider the cyclic group generated by $a$ and denote it by $C_{n}$.

It is easy to see that these two generate whole of $D_{n}$

Next observe that $C_{n}$ is normal in $D_{n}$ and $C_{2}\cap C_{n}=\{e\}$.

Above arguments shows that $D_{n}$ is the semi direct product of $C_{2}$ and $C_{n}$

**Now coming to the point**, Can we define a non trivial action of $C_{2}$ on $C_{n}$.

Comment: Yes, because that is part of being a (non-trivial) semidirect product.

Comment: Can you please explain. I mean the definition of semidirect product, I am using does not include any such thing.

Comment: When realizing the semidirect product internally, the action is by conjugation.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So it means that we can consider the following action $C_{2}\times C_{n}\rightarrow C_{n}$ by $(b,a)=b^{-1}ab$. So this action is like inverting element of $C_{n}$

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often a semi-direct product $N \rtimes_{\varphi} H$ is given in terms of a homomorphism:

$\varphi: H \to \text{Aut}(N)$

In this case, $N = C_n = \langle a\rangle$, and $H = C_2 = \langle b\rangle$.

The (non-trivial) homomorphism $\varphi$ is defined thus:

$\varphi(b) = f$, where $f(a) = a^{-1}$ ($f$ is a homomorphism $C_n \to C_n$ since $C_n$ is abelian, and is clearly bijective, thus an automorphism). It is clear that $f(a^k) = (a^k)^{-1} = (a^{-1})^k$, for all integers $k$.

Since $\varphi \circ \varphi = \text{id}_{C_n}$, it should be clear this is a non-trivial homomorphism of $C_2$ into $\text{Aut}(C_n)$ (it's actually a monomorphism, but that's not that relevant, here).

Note that we can define an action of $C_2$ on $C_n$ by:

$b\cdot a = [\varphi(b)](a) = f(a) = a^{-1}$, and that this is the same action as:

$b\cdot a = a^b = b^{-1}ab = a^{-1}$.